# This could be caused by IIS not being setup to handle extensionless static files

Tags: ssl

---

The ACME server was probably unable to reach http://mydomain/.well-known/acme-challenge/LLtRq6EdfBLmxyhzlFEqL
kDXBUFLsQbaea6A5kiJxIo

Check in a browser to see if the answer file is being served correctly.

This could be caused by IIS not being setup to handle extensionless static
files. Here's how to fix that:
1. In IIS manager goto Site/Server->Handler Mappings->View Ordered List
2. Move the StaticFile mapping above the ExtensionlessUrlHandler mappings.
(like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvrL.png)
3. If you need to make changes to your web.config file, update the one
at C:\applications\letsencrypt\web_config.xml

---

Getting this error 
While creatng ssl certifcate using letsencrypt

tried 
1) If you can't browse to this configcheck file in your web browser (http://{your site}/.well-known/acme-challenge/configcheck then the Lets Encrypt service can't access the files it needs either.

=> configcheck is not getting created

You can edit the web.config file in this folder to get extensionless files working, then you can re-request your certificate. A mimeMap entry for either "." or ".*" usually works depending on your operating system version.

=> Edited web.config tried both "." or ".*"

No success

Can anyone please suggest steps to follow 
i am using aws sever windows 2008 R2

Comment: 1.Goto Site/Server->Mime Types
2.Add a mime type of .* (application/octet-stream)
3.Goto Site/Server->Handler Mappings->View Ordered List
Move the StaticFile mapping above the ExtensionlessUrlHandler mappings.
(like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/nkvrL.png)

Tried this but no help

Answer (score 1):

If you have redirected your domain name from http to https 
in virtual host of apache http.conf file

This will cause this issue 
please comment that redirect and try it

Got solved